# Not sure if I should create multiple custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, seo

I am working on a projects that has different tutorials, such as js, html, css and etc.

I was initially thinking to create one custom post type for each tutorials, but after some research, I think maybe it is better to create one custom post type called Tutorial, and have different categories under it, like js, html, css and etc.

I am not sure which approach is better. I am more concern about the performance and SEO. Can someone share the thoughts, pros and cons with each approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is just way too opinion based and cannot really be based on facts, open ended questions like this does not fit the scope of the site. Please see [ask]

Comment: @Pieter Goosen: got it, question closed

Comment: FWIW I think the latter (tutorial post type + taxonomy) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create multi custom post type, Think your project scope clearly.For Tutorials like html,css, js or other tutorials, you should create only tutorials custom post type. So that

```
yourdomain.com/tutorials
yourdomain.com/tutorials/html/
yourdomain.com/tutorials/js
```

It's more readable and good for SEO. Analyze the project flow clearly and then you could configure well for that. Good luck in codes :)